# xCode 7: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run my app in the simulator, everything works fine. But when I try to run it on my device(iOS 8.4) I get this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode-    beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: file not found: /Users/simen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tablesearch-doxaezkgsjeztnfkntkvhvhrjkdj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/tablesearch.app/tablesearch
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone know what to do?
Thanks

Comment: do a clean before running, also try deleting app on mobile,

Comment: Tried to Clean, and build fails when I try to run on iPhone

Comment: Have you checked your build and run target version ?

Answer (score 20):

To solve this problem:

- Go to your project setting page
- Select your project (left side)
- Click the "Build Settings" tab
- Search "Bitcode"
- Set "Enable Bitcode" to "No"

Comment: This worked, but what was that all about? It happened all of a sudden!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. But previously it was working with BITCODE=YES, why not now?

Answer (score 4):

your device version is iOS 8.4, but project target iOS 9.0 ? 
Change your project target to iOS 8.4 and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Either the SDKROOT setting in your project got corrupted with extra spaces (assuming those spaces **are not** a typo) or something is wrong with your copy of Xcode (if those spaces **are** a typo).

If it isn't one of those two things, then look inside the .xcodeproj bundle and open the project.pbxproj file with a text editor and search for "Xcode-    beta.app" (with those extra spaces).  Find that, figure out which setting is wrong based on the name of the field that has that as part of its value, and fix the relevant setting in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Project, and now everything works fine.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation the problem was a **faulty plugin**.

Try removing any non common plugins and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..

- Go to your project setting page
- Select your project (left side)
- Click the "General" tab
- Select the app in "Host Application"